# c3p0 connection pool saveorupdate with blob data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

we are facing issue with c3p0 connection pool. The object persist fine if
save without blob data, add blob to the object then session save method fails. even it is not coming exception handler and it is directly going to finally block
Where session.flush throws  assertion exception as the the new id is not assigned to object.

Is this issue faced by any one. Is this issue with configuration?

hibernate configuration

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>  
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
<prop key="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">4</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>


<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.validationQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" >/var/lucene/indexes</prop>
```

Thanks
Mohsin

Comment: I don't think its having some relation with `connection pool`, connection pools just hold your tcp connection, you should be looking at your db driver or jvm activities.

Comment: I tried without c3p0 connection pool and even i tried with HikariCP connection pool it worked.

Comment: leave c3p0, HikariCp is way much better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Caught Throwable object and printed stack trace.

`catch( Throwable e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Got the

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V is abstract
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$5$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$2$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)

It seems the c3p0 jar file using old, Downloaded newer version 0.0.95.2 version, it worked

Thanks